# Find a string inside an other in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have this code.

```
SELECT
`realestates`.`ID`,
`realestates`.`Code`
FROM
`realestates`
WHERE INSTR('S47ES35ES12E',('S' + realestates.ID + 'E'));
```

I have a realestates table like this.

```
ID Code    
1  4671    
2  4890    
...    
12  5031    
...    
34  5033    
35  6060    
36  6061    
...    
47  7011   
48  7012   
... 
147 8000    
148 8101
```

How can I change it so, it would find the realestate only with ID 47, ID 35 and ID 12? Because now I have a bunch of records. It looks like my 'S' and 'E' strings are completely ignored so it finds all those records that has 47 in their ID number somewhere so this can result ID 147 and ID 47 as well.

This "my favourites" string 'S47ES35ES12E' is a list of preselected real estates. I just want to print them on one page but my code pulls in other real estates as well who are actually not in this "my favourites" string.

Comment: Your syntax, `'S' + realestates.ID + 'E'` is not MySQL.  Your query might work if you did `concat('S', realestates.ID, 'E')` instead.

Comment: It's really bad design to store lists in a single field. But if you insist on doing it, use comma-separated lists, so you can use `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE  'S47ES35ES12E' LIKE concat('%S', realestates.ID, 'E%')
```

Comment: This will give you what you want, however it really isn't a good or efficient method. Ideally you want to store your favourites in another table and then `JOIN` the resultsets together

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - cheers for the update! Silly oversight on my part :$

Comment: . . Not that silly, given that the OP has the invalid syntax in the question.